# How to install iOS12 simulator in xcode14.2

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

my mac Version is Ventura 13.2 ,Xcode version is 14.2 , when opening setting->Platforms ,Can't see iOS12.4 simulator, minimum version is 13.7。so I Got the 12.4 emulator from another computer，and put it in this directory '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes' .

after installed, I Open the project file, but cannot see the iOS12 simulator

so How to install iOS12 simulator in xcode14.2 ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7kwP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmx5O.png)